# result_of<>::type when applied to member pointer

Tags: c++, c++11

```
template<class C, class F>
struct _fooClass {
    const C& obj_;          // any class
    const F& fn_;           // pointer to member field of C
    _fooClass(C& obj, F fn) : obj_(obj), fn_(fn) {}
    auto operator()() -> decltype(obj_.*fn_) {
        return obj_.*fn_;   // returns the value stored in this member
    }    
    // declare an operator that converts 
    // _fooClass to decltype(obj_.*fn_) 
};

template<class C, class F>
//
// version 1: let compiler deduce the type
// auto fooClass(C obj, const F& fn) 
//    result: compiles
//
// version 2: explicit write down the type b/c compiler hasn't implemented auto return type deduction
// auto fooClass(C obj, const F& fn) -> typename std::result_of<decltype(fn)(C)>::type
//    result: error (g++) cannot bind 'const int' lvalue to 'std::__success_type<int&&>::type {aka int&&}'
//            error (VC)  cannot convert const int to int&
// 
auto fooClass(C obj, const F& fn) -> typename std::result_of<decltype(fn)(C)>::type {
    _fooClass<C, F> c(obj, fn);
    return c();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const B b{1};
    //auto x = foo(b, &B::field2);
    auto x = fooClass(b, &B::field2);
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Background: _fooClass eventually should become a transformer that's part of an iterator.  For example,

```
struct B {
   int field1;
}
template<class Enumerator>
void user_function(Enumerator e) {
    for (auto i : e) {
    }
}
// what's the return type?
template<class CONTAINER, class F>
auto enumerate(CONTAINER& c, F fn) {
    return ....; // create an enumerator
}
void main() {
   vector<B> vec;
   user_function(enumerate(b, &b::field1));
}
```

`user_function` takes an arbitrary enumerator of some type, and the source behind the enumerator comes from a `vector<B>`.

Questions:

1. How to make fooClass compile if auto return type deduction is not available?
2. The bigger question is: how to write an enumerator that takes an arbitrary iterator (wrt iterator_category) of type A, wrap and turn it into an iterator (in the same category as the source iterator) of type B in conjunction with a member field, member function, or normal function.
   The C# equivalent would be `IEnumerable<B> IEnumerable<A>.Select(Func<A, B> f)`

Comment: For `result_of`, value categories matter. Your actual call is on a `const C` lvalue, so `const C&` instead of `C`. Also, you have dangling references all over the place. Finally, what you are looking for is [`transform_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html).

Comment: @T.C.  I edited the question to show the usage in user_function.  Would you explain where are dangling references?